How to fix this: AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'custom_id'
I know exactly what the problem is, but I do not understand how I can assume that the button I need is pressed exactly like that. I used the "custom_id" parameter, but I do not know how to count and check this parameter in "on_interaction".
I'll tell you a little bit about the code, I'm creating a form for sending requests, but I ran into the problem that after a while the button itself stops working. I searched for a solution on this platform, did as required, but ran into a new problem, the "interaction" parameter does not have the "custom_id" attribute/parameter. Now I do not know how to count the button click in "on_interaction"
@bot.hybrid_command(description='Form')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def req_form(ctx):
    global green
    button = discord.ui.Button(label='Отправить Реквест', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id='req')
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Отправка реквестов',
                          description= 'Тут вы можете отправить ваш уровень нашему модератору, а тот перекинет уровень GD-модераторам на оценку!\n```Правила реквестов```\n- Ваш уровень должен соответствовать как правилам проекта, так и правилам игры\n- Нельзя пользоватся данной системой не в серьёз. За ложный реквест вы получите наказание, а позже и блокировку доступа к системе!\n- Вы получите такое-же наказание как и за прошлый пункт, если вы отправите в анкете рофл-уровень!\n- Не используйте систему чрезмерно часто!',
                          color=green)
    embed.set_image(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1051774366758735902/1236724216712134706/REQ-05-05-2024_1.png?ex=66390cae&is=6637bb2e&hm=28ad7939dafe85e3ba606c3b09178e375438f12060eb7de8f4cfda4eb0eebed6&')
    view = discord.ui.View(button)
    await ctx.reply(embed=embed, view=view)

@bot.event
async def on_interaction(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    async def give_req_form(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        modal = ReqQuestion()
        await interaction.response.send_modal(modal) # make a code...
        await modal.wait()
    
    if interaction.custom_id == 'req':
        await give_req_form(interaction)

I was going through the parameters

This is not a common way to add buttons. In the actual documentation, it says this is a low level function that shouldn't be used normally. See here for how to make buttons

An Interaction object does not have the custom_id attribute. I think you actually want to get the id of the item related to that interaction. You can try something like:
item_id = interaction.data.get("custom_id")
if item_id == "req":
    await give_req_form(interaction)


This is not true. In the pycord docs, there is a custom id for interactions

But you are assuming that the author is using Pycord. From the moment he gets AttributeError when accessing the custom_id attribute on the Interaction object, we assume that he is using discord.py purely.

It's in their tags, they're definitely using pycord

Looking at the code he made available, he is using discord.py purely

And to repeat: if he got AttributeError when accessing custom_id, he is demonstrably using discord.py purely.

why do they have the py-cord tag then
